# How to connect with Firebase and Android?? please

Tags: java, android, firebase

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Fuser\AndroidStudioProjects\NEW\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Fuser.gradle\caches\6.7.1\scripts\1if03h4fyufvb0fl5dcuqaurv).
> BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '*BuildScript*' class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @27efef64)

how can i solve this problems.... please i need help

```
plugins {id 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'}
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anew"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'}
```

Where should i put this one...?

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and what went wrong???

Answer (score 1):

inside plugins instead of apply plugin write id. `id 'com.android.application'` `id 'com.google.gms.google-services'` like this and try to build Gradle. For better understanding, you can refer to this [project](https://github.com/prabinkumarsahu28/RandomChat/blob/master/RandomChat/app/build.gradle).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the plugins block in your build.gradle file by

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
```